# How to pass an array of checked/unchecked checkbox values to PHP email generator?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have added a checkbox to a form that the user can dynamically add rows to.  You can see the form [here](http://www.bodhitreebrighton.org.uk/bookingtest.html).

I use an array to pass the values for each row to a PHP email generator, and all works fine for other inputs, but I can't get the checkbox to work.  The checkbox input currently looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[]" value="Yes">
```

Then in the PHP I have this:

```
$mailing = trim(stripslashes($_POST['mailing'][$i]));
```

But it is not working as expected, i.e. I am only seeing 'Yes' for the first checkbox checked, and nothing for subsequent checkboxes that are checked.

One further issue is that I would like the value 'No' to be generated for unchecked checkboxes.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

**Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="bookingenginetest.php">
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="mailing[]" value="Yes">
                <label>Full Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name[]">
                <label>Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email[]">
                <label>Telephone:</label> <input type="text" name="telephone[]">
                <span class="remove">Remove</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class="add">Add person</span><br /><br /><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
            </p>

        </form>
```

**Cloning script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $(".add").click(function() {
                    var x = $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
                    x.find('input').each(function() { this.value = ''; });
                    return false;
                });

                $(".remove").click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                });

            });
```

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are NOT submitted with the rest of the form. If you want "no", you'd have to keep track of which checkboxes are on the form and make a list of which ones weren't checked. The alternative is some javascript at submit time to loop over all the checkboxes and build up a list of unchecked ones and submit that value as another form field.

Comment: Suggest making each new row 'checked' by default by adding the 'checked' attribute so it's less likely that the user will submit an unchecked row.
`<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[]" value="" checked />`

Answer (score 5):

```
$mailing = array();
foreach($_POST as $v){
    $mailing[] = trim(stripslashes($v));
}
```

To handle unchecked boxes it would be better to set each checkbox with a unique value:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[1]" value="Yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[2]" value="Yes">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[a]" value="Yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[b]" value="Yes">
```

Then have a list of the checkboxes:

```
$boxes = array(1,2,3);
$mailing = array();
$p = array_key_exists('mailing',$_POST) ? $_POST['mailing'] : array();
foreach($boxes as $v){
    if(array_key_exists($v,$p)){
        $mailing[$v] = trim(stripslashes($p[$v]));
    }else{
        $mailing[$v] = 'No';
    }
}

print_r($mailing);
```

You could also use this with a number of checkboxes instead:

```
$boxes = 3;
$mailing = array();
$p = array_key_exists('mailing',$_POST) ? $_POST['mailing'] : array();
for($v = 0; $v < $boxes; $v++){
    if(array_key_exists($v,$p)){
        $mailing[$v] = trim(stripslashes($p[$v]));
    }else{
        $mailing[$v] = 'No';
    }
}

print_r($mailing);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would this method work with the cloning method I am using to dynamically add rows?

Comment: @Nick: As long as you keep some sort of running index and increment it anytime you dynamically add a row and decrement it when you remove one).  You would need to send the script the total number of checkboxes and modify my code a bit to use a number of checkboxes instead of a list.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

With an array of checkboxes in the html like so...

```
<input type="hidden" name="something[]" value="off" />
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="something[]" value="off" />
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" />
<input type="hidden" name="something[]" value="off" />
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" />
```

I then fix the posted array with this function...

```
$_POST[ 'something' ] = $this->fixArrayOfCheckboxes( $_POST[ 'something' ] );
function fixArrayOfCheckboxes( $checks ) {
    $newChecks = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < count( $checks ); $i++ ) {
        if( $checks[ $i ] == 'off' && $checks[ $i + 1 ] == 'on' ) {
            $newChecks[] = 'on';
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            $newChecks[] = 'off';
        }
    }
    return $newChecks;
}
```

This will give me an array with values of either 'on' or 'off' for each (and every) checkbox.

Note that the hidden input MUST be BEFORE the checkbox input in order for the function to work right.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value for each checkbox to something unique:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[]" value="Yes-1"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[]" value="Yes-2">
```

etc.  In order to do this from your jQuery code, **add another line** that assigns the value to the new checkbox:

```
x.find('input:checkbox').each(function() { this.value='Yes-'+n; });
```

You'll have to define `n` on the initial page load.  Assuming you start with only one "person", just add right above your `$(".add").click` handler:

```
var n=1;
```

And then:

- in your `$(".add").click` handler, increment the value of `n`
- in your `$(".remove").click` handler, decrement the value of `n`

Comment: @AJ Not sure how I would do that, as subsequent rows on the form are added dynamically using cloning.

Comment: Updated my answer...you can't do that? (above)

Comment: @AJ No, it's not clear to me how I would generate unique values using the cloning method.  I have added the form and cloning script to my question above.

Comment: Actually it looks like the line **after** the `clone()` is setting the value to empty string.  What is the form going to send to the server for a checkbox with **no value**?

Comment: @AJ I'd like it to send the value "Yes" for each checked checkbox and "No" for each unchecked checkbox

Comment: That's not really how checkboxes work...if it's not checked, it doesn't get sent to the server.  If you need to know **explicitly** which checkboxes are unchecked, you'll have to implement another mechanism to do this.  There are different techniques, one of which is to use a hidden field for each checkbox.   See this link:  http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/09/posting-unchecked-checkboxes-in-html-forms/

Comment: @AJ  OK, thanks.  Yes, I have seen this method of using a hidden field.  Leaving aside the unchecked issue for a moment, though, am I right in thinking your suggestion isn't suited to the cloning method?  If so, perhaps I will switch to using a drop-down menu, with 'Yes' and 'No' options.  I'd rather use a checkbox, as I think it is more minimal/elegant, but it seems rather complicated for my level of knowledge.

Comment: I think you could assign a different value to each checkbox. I'll update my answer with the code.

Comment: @AJ.  Thanks, I managed to get your answer working, but of course the values returned in the email are Yes-1, Yes-2, etc., rather than just 'Yes', and then there is still the issue of multiple unchecked checkboxes.  I am now thinking I would be better off using a drop-down menu after all.  Thanks for your help anyway.  Nick

Comment: Extending your solution, this could do a better job. `onsubmit` add this: `var i = 0;` `$(form).find('input:checkbox').each(function() {       $(this).attr('name', 'mailing[' + i + ']'); i++;});`

Answer (score 1):

To get checked and unchecked both values in POST place a hidden field with exactly the same name but with opposite value as compared to the original chkbox value such that in this case the value will be '0'

```
<input type="hidden" name="chk_name[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="chk_name[]"  value="1"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="chk_name[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="chk_name[]"  value="1"/>

<?php 
function getAllChkboxValues($chk_name) {
    $found = array(); //create a new array 
    foreach($chk_name as $key => $val) {
        //echo "KEY::".$key."VALue::".$val."<br>";
        if($val == '1') { //replace '1' with the value you want to search
            $found[] = $key;
        }
    }
    foreach($found as $kev_f => $val_f) {
        unset($chk_name[$val_f-1]); //unset the index of un-necessary values in array
    }   
    final_arr = array(); //create the final array
    return $final_arr = array_values($chk_name); //sort the resulting array again
}
$chkox_arr = getAllChkboxValues($_POST['chk_name']); //Chkbox Values
echo"<pre>";
print_r($chkox_arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
<span>
<input class="chkBox" onchange="if($(this).is(':checked')){$(this).parent().find('.hidVal').prop('disabled',true);}else{$(this).parent().find('.hidVal').prop('disabled', false);}" type="checkbox" checked name="session[]" value="checked_value_here" />
<input type="hidden" class="hidVal" name="session[]" value="un_checked_value_here" />
</span>
<span>
<input class="chkBox" onchange="if($(this).is(':checked')){$(this).parent().find('.hidVal').prop('disabled',true);}else{$(this).parent().find('.hidVal').prop('disabled', false);}" type="checkbox" checked name="session[]" value="checked_value_here" />
<input type="hidden" class="hidVal" name="session[]" value="un_checked_value_here" />
</span>
```