# Pass Value for an unchecked array checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get the values of the unchecked checkboxes.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
 <div class="">
  <label>
   <input class="ValAHide" type="hidden" name="ValA[]" value="">
   <input onchange="if($(this).is(':checked')){$(this).parent().find('.ValAHide').prop('disabled',true);}else{$(this).parent().find('.ValAHide').prop('disabled', false);}"  type="checkbox" class="ValA ValAVisible" name="ValA[]" value="Value A" />&nbsp;Value A
  </label>
 </div>
 <div align="right">
  <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success add">Add More</button>
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
 </div>
</form>



    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
   var html = '';
   html += '<div class=""><label>';
   html += '<input class="ValAHide" type="hidden" name="ValA[]" value="">';
   html += '<input onchange="if($(this).is(":checked")){$(this).parent().find(".ValAHide").prop("disabled",true);}else{$(this).parent().find(".ValAHide").prop("disabled", false);}"  type="checkbox" class="ValA ValAVisible" name="ValA[]" value="Value A" />&nbsp;Value A';
   html += '</label></div>';
   $('#form').append(html);
  });
  $('#form').on('submit', function(event){
        });
 });
</script>
```

Scenario :
I'm trying to pass the unchecked checkbox value. In order to do that, I used hidden inputs and onchange script verifies if the checkbox is checked, then it disables the hidden input. it works fine initially. 
But when i try to append more input fields inside the form, it onchange script is not working to disable the checked hidden values and it pass both hidden value and the checked checkbox value..

Comment: Your question similar on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376112/how-to-pass-an-array-of-checked-unchecked-checkbox-values-to-php-email-generator). Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6376158/7678419) solution

Comment: Anyhow, Issue Solved. I just replaced the quotes (" " with ` `) and it starts working as expected.